# How can I set decimal separator depended of Locale in Table using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am writting a program that solves the Knapsack problem. I have several classes that solves the problem packed into a `.jar` and i have to use this `.jar` in another project. One of these classes is named `Item` and it is defined by 3 fields: `String name`, `int weight` and `double value` and another class that returns list of all these items. What i have to do is to show in `Table` values with separator that is set depending on the `Locale.getDefault()`. Once it is a `.` and once `,`. What i've tried was to `tableColumnItemsValue.setCellValueFactory(pvt);` where `pvt` would be something that sets decimal separator. Then i tried:

```
PropertyValueFactory pvt = new PropertyValueFactory("value").call(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()).getDecimalSeparator());
```

And of course it did not work, cuz im returning `char` to `PropertyValueFactoy`. I have no idea how to do that.

Here is my code before i started to "make it work":

```
    listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();
    observableListOfItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listOfItems);
    listProperty.set(observableListOfItems);
    tableView.setItems(observableListOfItems);
    tableView.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(listProperty);

    tableColumnItemsName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    tableColumnItemsWeight.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weight"));
    tableColumnItemsValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("value"));
```

Would you help?

Comment: you need a custom cellfactory (_not_ cellValueFactory!) that configures the text with a Numberformat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i've solved my problem. If someone had a similiar problem, here is a solution:

```
tableColumnItemsValue.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item, String> param) {
        double value = param.getValue().getItemValue();
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault()));
        return new SimpleStringProperty(df.format(value));
    }
});
```

Comment: no that's wrong and not what I suggested in my comment ;) A cellValueFactory is for providing the observable data (in your context the value as DoubleProperty), a cellFactory is for configuring the visual representation of that value, f.i. by formatting it.